# Can we automate web pages in Safari using XCUITest? without Appium

Tags: swift, mobile-safari, xctest, xcuitest

Is there a github repo that illustrates automation of the web page via Safari browser using XCUITest. No usage of Appium or other mobile framework

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can by using the safari

```
public let safari = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")

safari.launch()
safari.textFields["Address"].tap()
safari.textFields["Address"].typeText(url)

url is your desired web address

After this you can interact the web page via 
safari.buttons["xxxx"].firstMatch
safari.textFields["yyyy"].firstMatch
```